# Blender - Chevron Markings - Design

Tags: modifiers

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

I want to design chevron markings at different angles so this template has to be flexible (not sure if I should group or join the objects?):

EDIT: I forgot to mension, I want to keep the spacing between arrows as well.

Thank you!

EDIT:
I managed to do the chevrons but I got stuck when cutting them along the mesh. Actually I used 2 paths to restrict the border of cut. They are perfectly alligned. I'm stuck with them as I don't know how to convert them to a mesh.I tried ctrl + J and and alt + C but I'm missing the closing path to get the shape out of it. Almost there but as you see I'm missing something. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the default cube, scale it in the Z direction to make it quite flat (say to 0.05). Extrude two adjacent faces to make a chevron with very long arms.

[image: big chevron]

Add an Array modifier and configure it to repeat the single chevron at the required spacing. You can use the Constant offset to manually adjust this.

[image: many chevrons]

Create a second mesh to enclose the region where you want the chevrons. This must be *manifold* - ie, it needs to fully enclose the space.

[image: bounding mesh]

Select the original mesh (the chevrons) and add a Boolean modifier set to Intersect with Object set to the bounding mesh you just created.

Select the bounding mesh and Hide it by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> and you should now see just the chevrons that were within the bounding box.

[image: result]

Finally, you can Apply the modifiers and delete the bounding mesh as it's no longer required.

Comment: I just realised you've edited your question so it's no longer just the chevrons. This answer will give you the chevrons - curving it is a whole different ball game if you want to keep the dimensions unaffected - as is automatically adding the bounding lines. Hopefully this will give you a start.

Comment: That's a very good tutorial. Thank you very much. I managed to do the chevrons easly. I also applied curve to the chevrons without any problems. I will edit my question to show, where I got and where I got stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

1. Select the second arrow
2. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale then Hit <kbd>X</kbd> to scale along the x-axis.
3. Repeat step1-2 for the rest of the arrows

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want. I will modify my question to describe what I mean.